# Notify Windows system applications font has been uninstalled/deleted

Tags: c++, c, winapi

When installing fonts temporarily using `AddFontResource/RemoveFontResource` applications such as Adobe Photoshop, Illustrator recognize the change accordingly in real time.

The problem is when you permanently install a font, and make the font available after a system reboot by copying the file to the windows fonts directory + adding the font to the system registry, deleting the font after this point requires a complete reboot for system wide applications to realize what fonts are available.

My question is after permanently deleting a font file, removing the file from WINDIR/Fonts and removing it's entry from the system registry what needs to be done to inform system wide applications the font is not available and to update their lists accordingly? I was thinking `SHChangeNotify`might be the right direction but utterly unsure.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the application in question to me. They probably assumed people might add fonts but never bothered to handle the case where they remove them.

Comment: In *nix environments you simply copy the font to whatever folder or delete it nice and simple. An interesting work a round is to delete the font from win/fonts, remove the val from the registry then call AddFontResource again. Sure the font is still available to system applications but in the font manager app Im developing it is effectively deleted.It just happens to be available until a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You should send the `WM_FONTCHANGE` message to all top-level windows (using `HWND_BROADCAST` as the target of a `SendMessage` call):

```cpp
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I've done that. Probably need to edit my question.

Comment: So, are you manually removing the font from the system fonts folder? Or is your application doing that? If the latter, it should be doing so *via* a call to `RemoveFontResource`. See the "Remarks" section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-removefontresourcew

Comment: The who process is done with a command line app. RemoveFontResource only removes the font from the fonts table.

Comment: @TomShaw Make sure the font isn't listed in the font registry and restart the system to ensure the font is unloaded from all sessions. Then send the `WM_FONTCHANGE` message to inform system wide applications the font is not available.